# How to create a dynamic allocation array with unknown size in struct in c++

Tags: pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was trying to create a struct with an unknown size array. here's what I think, but it seems to have a problem because memcheck report an error.I'm not sure if this is legal in c++

```
        struct information
    {
        std::string name;
        int x=0;
        int* score=new int[x];
    }
```

Comment: I tried implementing it with Class and it seems to be working but I get a warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I guess the problem is when declaring struct  variable in main, x is a fixed number but score should be dynamic allocation. I don't know if there is a better to create an unknown size array in struct.

Comment: Well before C++11, variable Sized Arrays weren't possible, You had to dynamically allocate space for the Array but It is possible to make variable sized arrays after C++11 So I think it is correct way to create a dynamic allocation array but don't forget to use the Delete keyword to prevent memory leaks